# Command to output its backend process

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, process, batch-file

I have an application running in windows that has an option to run a command (UI base). I'm pretty sure that the UI base backend is running in a cmd but I dont know what is the exact bin file.

The application itself has a lot of bin files and I dont know which one are being use by the "UI run a command option"

I wanted to have it run automated by creating a batch script (to which I'm new).

I couldn't start it because I dont knoe the cmd it's using.

I tried to run the "UI run a command option" and check tasks manager/tasklist but no processes are added.

So I was thinking to use the "UI run a command option" to input a command that will output its own backend process in a file in detailed.

Comment: I'm afraid we need to know what product you are using.

Comment: The tool we are using is Tripwire Enterprise Thank you.